# Pick specific column value in a group of rows based on condition

Tags: mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I am working with mariadb server version 10.6.4.

This is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp_dba` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `case_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `arrival` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `departure` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

Here is some example data:

```
INSERT INTO `tmp_dba` VALUES
(1,10,1000,'2018-10-02','2019-04-25'),
(2,10,1000,'2019-04-26','2019-05-01'),
(3,10,1000,'2019-05-02',NULL),
(4,20,2000,'2018-11-21',NULL),
(5,20,2001,'2018-11-21',NULL),
(6,20,2002,'2018-11-21',NULL),
(7,30,3000,'2019-03-04','2022-01-01'),
(8,30,3001,'2019-03-04','2022-01-01'),
(9,30,3002,'2019-03-04','2022-01-01'),
(10,30,3003,'2019-03-04','2022-01-01'),
(11,30,3004,'2019-03-04','2022-01-01');
```

What I would like to achieve is determine the MIN(arrival) of each group of case_id and client_id and in case departure is not null MAX(departure) should be displayed otherwise null.

I want to end up with just one row per client providing the the data mentioned above.

For example for case_id = 10 I want to see 1 row like that:
`10;1000;2018-10-02;NULL`.

For case_id = 20 the result should be 4 rows, because of 4 different combinations of case_id and client_id.

For case_id = 30 there should be 5 rows shown, because of 5 different combinations of case_id and client_id.

I must be doing something wrong when using group by.

### Further Information:

- Data is consecutive in the meaning that a new record entered will have a higher ID than the old one. Also a new record will be - relative to the one before - in the future, always. This does not mean that the next record always would have an arrival the day after last departure.
- A new record in the table for the same customer will always set the departure date of the previous record. The previous record departure in that case can not be null.
- When there is no departure and the client is "in" still, departure will be null always.
- Departure must be less than arrival unless departure is null.
- Arrival can not be null.

Is this doable?

### Solution

```
SELECT 
-- First solution, but wrong, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) avoids error below
-- ID, case_id, client_id, <-- only_full_group_by - error
GROUP_CONCAT(ID), case_id, client_id,
MIN(arrival) AS arrival,
IF(COUNT(departure) = COUNT(*), MAX(departure), NULL) AS departure
FROM tmp_dba
GROUP BY case_id, client_id
ORDER BY case_id, client_id
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Steffi

Comment: You only have 3 rows for client_id = 20! So, for client_id = 10, you **only** want the first arrival date and `NULL` for departure date since there isn't one for the last record? Do the previous arrival and departure dates have to be consecutive or can they be anything? I presume that arrival **must** be less than departure **unless** departure is NULL? I also presume that you can't have a NULL arrival date? Please put all information **back into the question and not as an answer to my comment!**. You can let me know by putting the `@` symbol followed by my handle in a comment below!

Comment: @Vérace - get VACCINATED NOW - lucky me, you are around again :) I have updated my question with the answers to yours. I tried @... last time also but it got cut every time. Hope this time it will work. Thanks.

Comment: "archive" or "achieve"??

Comment: Please provide a case with multiple rows being output, but with _some_ of the dates being different.  (I am unclear on how the goals interact.)

Comment: @Stefanie - take a look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3fd2814d10954708e325e28845cfad91) - trying to reply! Look in particular at what happens if you change the `sql_mode` by adding `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` - MySQL (and derivatives) **incredibly** will return rubbish if this isn't set - only became default in MySQL 8. Even more incredibly MariaDB 10.6 doesn't have this as its default - make it **your** default! See what works with PostgreSQL - normally a guide to good behaviour! I've given up working with MySQL and its derivatives and trying to figure out its bugs!

Comment: @Vérace - get VACCINATED NOW - Thanks a lot again. Your input is very very precious for me. I studied your fizzle and again learned a lot. Btw, for mariadb I use "ANALYZE" instead of "EXPLAIN ANALYZE". Just refering to the error messages in the fizzle, but I am pretty sure you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Do a search for `mysql set profiling` and look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c9e185930c41cc4f7525b89f98dd829). `EXPLAIN` on its own tells you very little! EXPLAIN ANALYZE (>= 8.0.18) gives you a plan! BTW, when trying to use @ to inform people that you've responded, some people are notified by default - normally the OP of the post **and** the person under whose comment you are posting. You may not get the name completion widget come up. It's always better to try and include the name, as someone else posting may get in before you!

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW - finally I managed it to study the explainations and hints you gave in your fiddle. I am really impressed on how you guided me through my question. I hope I got it all but for sure I learned a lot. I can not image how I could have learned it without your help and want to thank you for all your help again. Two things are not clear to me yet. I did not found an error with the execution of "dodgy implementation of LAST_*" functions. Also regarding profiling I need to figure out how to get an execution plan with mariadb.

Comment: [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0b060fd2506fedf5385a549a60b98309) is the best (and standard) way of providing the answer you want! It raised a few issues for me so I was testing it... Compare [side-by-side](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&rdbms2=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=0c9e185930c41cc4f7525b89f98dd829) PostgreSQL and MariaDB for "dodgy implementation..." - if it works for PostgreSQL, you can assume that it's normally OK!

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW - Agreed with the solution you came up with. I applied it. As for the "dodgy implementation" I got it all also. To see it sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,...' has to be turned on. Thank you so much for all your help and time again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What code do you have so far?  I assume you are using `GROUP BY case_id, client_id`.

To discover whether *any* `departure` is `NULL` (across a group) is with `COUNT(*) = COUNT(departure)`.  This is because `COUNT(*)` counts all rows; the other counts only rows where `departure IS NOT NULL`.  So, this is how you might make the departure expression:

```
IF(COUNT(departure) = COUNT(*), MAX(departure), NULL)
```

**More**

Your proposed solution has the "only_full_group_by" problem since it asks for multiple things.  Change `ID` to `GROUP_CONCAT(ID)`.

Also, it would be a slight optimization to change the `ORDER BY` to match the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer. Based on your answer, I extended my question with a solution part. Does this make sense to you? Thanks again. Apologizes - I cannot manage it to copy your name using at Rick James at the beginning of that message. It is cut off always when saved. @Rick James

Comment: @Stefanie - (StackExchange removes spaces when generating "@" handles.)

Comment: @Stefanie - I added some more to my Answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips and your review of my solution. I changed it according to your advise and learned again. @Rick James

Comment: Just trying to put notification in the right format at the right place and omitting spaces. Still it does not work. I am using tor browser with restrictions to java script or I am too dumb. No way, (at)Rick does not work, (at)RickJames (one word) doesn't. Trying (at)rickjames also... nothing is working (all tried at the beginning of the comment. I give up, hopefully (at)Rick James at the end of my previous comment did reach you.

Comment: @Stefanie - I was alerted twice, perhaps merely because the Comments were on the end of my Answer.  I can't explain why your attempts failed.  when I do just 3 keystrokes, (at)s(tab), it spells out (at)Stefanie for me.  I would expect (at)s(tab) to work for you.  I am not familiar with "tor"; maybe it has some JS or CSS limitations.